# Find node id by field value

Tags: services

I am loooking for the way to find a node by the value of custom field using XMLRPC.

Here is more context:
I am  developing an application to integrate our software with drupal 7.
The application is developed in java and it communictaes drupal via XMLRPC service.
I am able to perform all the basic CRUD operations on nodes and on files.
In order to synchronize drupal node and object of my application,
I am using drupal field, which contains id of the object in my application.
I fill this field every time I create new node in drupal.

I know to use node.index in order to find nodes match some particular fields values,
however I can not use "custom fields" in this method.

Please advise.

Comment: You need work with EntityFieldQuery: http://drupal.org/node/1343708

Comment: Great! It worked for me. The only issue, I had to write my own service module to implement access to EntityFieldQuery. So my question is whether it is availavle through some preinstalled/well known XMLRPC service module. I prefer to avoid a development of my own modules.

Comment: Services module provide hooks and its very simple to write your own module on top of it.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is what I've done. I just don't like the logistic... I prefer my app. could work with any drupal site without any additional installation on their side.